# JS How long until restart

Tags: javascript, time

I am currently trying to make a something in JS that will be able to tell me how long there is until a server restart. The server restarts at 00:00, 04:00, 08:00, 12:00, 16:00, 20:00. I am not sure as to how to approach this so if anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated. The main idea of this should be to look at the current time and work out how long until the next restart.

I am completely mine boggled so any help would be great!
Thanks!

Comment: I have solved this issue!

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by getting the current hours and minutes then running a while loop to see if the hours are greater than four if it then keeps taking away four hours. If it isn't then minus 4 from the current hour and there you go!